# How to render same page with different url using htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, url-rewriting

I have new domain and for now I want to render all url to home page.

eg.

```
abc.com/abc
abc.com/abc/xyz
abc.com/abc/xyz/123
abc.com/abc/abc/xyz/123/so_on
```

also url will show only current home page ( index.html (or .php) ) instead of

> "Not Found,  The requested URL /index.php was not found on this server."

How can I do that using htaccess?

Comment: First, I'm missing the http server. It may not be strictly necessary (I don't know the answer), but it may be needed to answer this question. Second, regarding "Also URL will show", do you mean you wish to forward all URI's to index.html or is this the current situation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a rewrite rule in .htaccess

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^.*$ index.php [NC,L]
```

This will send all requests to index.php file(or you can change it to index.htm etc.)

Answer (score 0):

also you can bypass static files like css/js and etc:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
```